# Bigquery CLI windows issue

Tags: google-bigquery

When I run a query for a table around 20Million records the job gets successful in other environments but when I run the same on Windows command line I get an error saying - You have encountered a bug in the BigQuery CLI.

> Query :  bq --quiet --format=csv --project_id="proj_id" query
>   --max_rows=999999999  " select ids from dataset.table group each by id"

Do the execution change according to OS? The same query works for 5 Million records

```
Error log


== UTC timestamp ==
  2015-02-19 08:33:16

== Error trace ==
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform/bq\bq.py", line 719, in RunSafely
    return_value = self.RunWithArgs(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform/bq\bq.py", line 1086, in RunWithArgs
    max_rows=self.max_rows)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bq\bigquery_client.py", line 846, in ReadSchemaAndJobRows
    return reader.ReadSchemaAndRows(start_row, max_rows)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bq\bigquery_client.py", line 2200, in ReadSchemaAndRows
    rows.append(self._ConvertFromFV(schema, row))
========================================
```

Comment: @Felipe Hoffa do you have any clue on this? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect there's a bug in the bq.py client on Windows somewhere in the code path that converts the reply from the query into something it can print. It may have something to do with the particular reply you receive.

Can you add a "--debug_mode" flag to your command line and reproduce the problem? That will allow the stack trace to be printed and we can figure out exactly where the problem is.